# How to hide one image into another one using LSB substitutuion?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, steganography

I am trying to implement a basic stenography technique in which I am replacing the LSB of the carrier image with the MSB of the message image. The LSB can belong to any of the RGB channel.

My approach is quite naive as I am looping the message_matrix and storing its MSB of a particular RGB channel in the corresponding LSB of the carrier_matrix. As the image size is not more than 1024 * 1024 the time complexity of performing this operation is O(n^2) but since I am using python the time taken is very high as compared to Java.

Can the same operation be performed in a more optimised way ?

```
def hide_using_bpcs(self, carrier_path, message_path, index, color_index):
            carrier_matrix = self.image_to_matrix(carrier_path)     
            message_matrix = self.image_to_matrix(message_path)              #use np.zeros

            for row_index, row in enumerate(message_matrix):
                for pixel_index, pixel in enumerate(row):
                    color = message_matrix[row_index][pixel_index][color_index]
                    msb = (color & 0xff) >> 7
                    carrier_pixel = carrier_matrix[
                        row_index][pixel_index][color_index]
                    carrier_matrix[row_index][pixel_index][
                        color_index] = self.set_bit(carrier_pixel, index, msb)

            stegano_image = self.matrix_to_image(carrier_matrix)
            return stegano_image
```

Now, for displaying a particular bit plane let say (Red 0), I am setting all the values of Green and Blue plane as 0 and retaining only the value of LSB (or the 0 bit) of the red color in the image. I have gone through some implementations done using openCV like [b,g,r = cv2.split(img)] but this is only splitting the image in 3 channels. What I want is to split a particular channel let say Red further into 8 Variations by retaining the value at the corresponding position.

```
    def display_bit_plane(self, path, color_index, color_bit):
            matrix = self.image_to_matrix(path)
            matrix = matrix.astype(int)
            result_matrix = self.image_to_matrix(path)
            mask = 1 << color_bit

            for row_index, row in enumerate(matrix):
                for pixel_index, pixel in enumerate(row):
                    for iterator in range(0, 3):
                        result_matrix[row_index][pixel_index][iterator] = 0 
                    color = matrix[row_index][pixel_index][color_index]
                    result_matrix[row_index][pixel_index][color_index] = self.set_bit(0, 7, ((color & mask) != 0))

            stegano_image = self.matrix_to_image(result_matrix)
            return stegano_image
```

I am using NumPy array for performing all the computations. However iterating it in usual way is very costly. Please provide some optimisation in the above two functions, so that these operations can be done in less than 1 second.

Edit 1 :

I have optimised the second function of retrieving the bit plane. If it can be further simplified please do tell. Color_index represents R, G, B as 0, 1, 2 respectively and color_bit is the bit position from 0-7.

```
def display_bit_plane_optimised(self, path, color_index, color_bit): 
        message_matrix = self.image_to_matrix(path)
        change_index = [0, 1, 2]
        change_index.remove(color_index)
        message_matrix[:, :, change_index] = 0
        mask = 1 << color_bit
        message_matrix = message_matrix & mask
        message_matrix[message_matrix == 1] = 1 << 7
        stegano_image = self.matrix_to_image(message_matrix)
        return stegano_image
```

Comment: Exactly how are you using BPCS steganography if you aren't substituting complex *areas* of the cover image for infomation? You seem to just be doing plain old LSB pixel substitution. This only requires bitwise operations, which can be vectorised, as you've shown. And why are you zeroing two of the colour planes when trying to display the other one? Can't you just select that one and work with a 2D array? Are the two images (cover and secret) guaranteed to have the same size?

Comment: Yes, you are right it is not BPCS but plain old LSB pixel substitution. Thus, I have edited the question. I am zeroing the other frames because I want to display a particular segment to the user. My application divides an image into 8(the bits) * 3(rgb) = 24 frames for the user to compare all and merge according to his wish. I was able to use vectorization in the second function however I have no idea how to implement the first function without any loops. Could you please mention some links to BPCS algorithm so that I could get a more clear idea on this topic as I am a new to it.

Comment: If you want to learn more about BPCS steganography, start with the original paper, [Kawaguchi, E., & Eason, R. O. (1999, January). Principles and applications of BPCS steganography.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.529.1136&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that applies to the whole array can be vectorised. If you want to apply an operation only on a part of the array, slice it.

I'm providing complete code so not to make assumptions about `image_to_matrix()` and `matrix_to_image()` methods. Take it from there.

I've kept your logic intact otherwise, but if you're only intending to embed the secret in the LSB, you can ditch `pixel_bit`, set its value to zero and simplify whatever constants result out of it. For example, in `embed()` you'd simply get `mask = 0xfe`, while any bitshifts by 0 are inconsequential.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

class Steganography:
    def embed(self, cover_file, secret_file, color_plane, pixel_bit):
        cover_array = self.image_to_matrix(cover_file)
        secret_array = self.image_to_matrix(secret_file)
        # every bit except the one at `pixel_bit` position is 1
        mask = 0xff ^ (1 << pixel_bit)
        # shift the MSB of the secret to the `pixel_bit` position
        secret_bits = ((secret_array[...,color_plane] >> 7) << pixel_bit)
        height, width, _ = secret_array.shape
        cover_plane = (cover_array[:height,:width,color_plane] & mask) + secret_bits
        cover_array[:height,:width,color_plane] = cover_plane
        stego_image = self.matrix_to_image(cover_array)
        return stego_image

    def extract(self, stego_file, color_plane, pixel_bit):
        stego_array = self.image_to_matrix(stego_file)
        change_index = [0, 1, 2]
        change_index.remove(color_plane)
        stego_array[...,change_index] = 0
        stego_array = ((stego_array >> pixel_bit) & 0x01) << 7
        exposed_secret = self.matrix_to_image(stego_array)
        return exposed_secret

    def image_to_matrix(self, file_path):
        return np.array(Image.open(file_path))

    def matrix_to_image(self, array):
        return Image.fromarray(array)
```

When I run it, it all completes within a second.

```
plane = 0
bit = 1

cover_file = "cover.jpg"
secret_file = "secret.jpg"

stego_file = "stego.png"
extracted_file = "extracted.png"

S = Steganography()
S.embed(cover_file, secret_file, plane, bit).save(stego_file)
S.extract(stego_file, plane, bit).save(extracted_file)
```

**Notes**

Your `display_bit_plane_optimised()` was reasonably optimised, but it had a bug if `color_bit` was anything but 0. The line

```
message_matrix = message_matrix & mask
```

zeros every other bit, but unless `color_bit` is 0, the values will be some other power of 2. So when you come to

```
message_matrix[message_matrix == 1] = 1 << 7
```

no pixel is modified. If you want to keep your way, you have to change the last line to

```
message_matrix[message_matrix != 0] = 1 << 7
```

My approach was simply to bring the embedded bit to the LSB position, zero out every other bit and then shift it to the MSB position with no conditionals.

Comment: Your optimisation is excellent, but the problem is that this won't work if the two images aren't of the same dimensions. My approach took that into consideration as I am looping over secret_file and storing its pixel in cover_file. However your method returned "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1050,1680) (800,800)". I can use PIL resize function to solve this problem, but is there any more proper way of handling this problem ?

Comment: Is it also possible to write a method that extracts the true form of the secret_message. For eg if the image is of white color and I want to provide the user both the true form (white) and the red plane result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lets us say I embed an image(secret_image) which is white in color in the red plane of the vessel image. So when I would extract this image(secret_image) using the extract method then I would receive an image(secret_image) that is red in color. But, the original color is white. My question is whether is it possible to retain the white color of the embedded image(secret_image) while extracting it. I have seen some tools which extract it properly so I am trying to provide that functionality also.But, I don't understand how to do so.

Comment: @AnkitJoshi Can you be a bit more clear what you mean white in colour? Maybe show an example? Each colour plane is on its own effectively a grayscale image. Once you put all three together, you get colour. Also, does the extraction method get input from the user to know from how many pixels to extract from the secret?

Comment: Never mind, It was just a misconception that got clear after viewing some examples. Thank You for your help.

Comment: @AnkitJoshi I've editted the `embed()` method to handle secret images smaller than the cover. You are advised though to check that the opposite doesn't happen for a stable execution of your code. Since the extraction doesn't have any additional information, it read from all the pixels, thus extracting the secret and any additional noise. If the extraction knows the size of the secret, you can simply slice it.